# Setting a custom countdown timer without reinitiating -- for second countdown upon onClick

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

Setting a custom countdown timer without reinitiating -- for second countdown upon onClick

Comment: Basically you want them to click on the button only once !?

Comment: Yes, I think your goal is to disable or remove the start button between the button press and the count of the first second?

Comment: But do you want to restart the countdown when the user presses start for the 2nd time? Because otherwise having the start button there is confusing?

Comment: Yea, with whatever the user's value is for input, the start button should restart with that value

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Define your variable at start
var seconds,
countdownTimer,
//Add a variable to know that a new click will not be valid
counting = false;
function startItUp() {
  var _count = function(){
    var secondsInput=document.getElementById('seconds').value;
    //If you have no value this will be 0
    seconds=parseInt(secondsInput) || 0;
    //The function does not pass as a string
    countdownTimer=setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
  }
  if(!counting){
    counting = true;
    _count();
  }
  /*
    //If you want to restart the count, remove the previous code and put this
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    _count();
  */
}

var numIntiate=1;
function secondPassed() {
  var minutes=Math.abs(Math.round((seconds - 30)/60));
  var remainingSeconds=seconds % 60;
  //If it is less than ten you will create an error if you have a zero as string
  //You should put lineal if/else statement
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML=minutes+':'+(remainingSeconds<10?'0'+ remainingSeconds: remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds==0) {
    //Stop the interval using its var
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML='Buzz Buzz';
    seconds=0;
    counting = false;
  }
  else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#input-container {
  padding: 25px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#start-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<h1>Timer</h1>
<div class="fluid-row" id="input-container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
<h1 id="countdown"></h1>
<h1 id="alert"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
<p>S</p>
<input type="number" id="seconds" placeholder="seconds">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="start-button" onclick="startItUp()">START</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a working basic structure for your needs, keeping it simple. This should help you, but you have to tweak it to include it in your project

```
var interval,
    elapsed,
    duration;

// This function should be called each time the user presses start:
var startCountDown = function (seconds) {
    // set the duration in ms:
    duration = seconds * 1000;
    // reset the elapsed time to 0 ms:
    elapsed = 0;
    // start the count down:
    interval = window.setInterval(countDown, 1000);
};

// Updates the counter and stops it when finished:
var countDown = function () {
    // increase elapsed # of ms:
    elapsed += 1000;
    // this is the # of seconds left:
    console.log((duration - elapsed) / 1000);
    // Check if we are done, if so, stop the countdown:
    if (elapsed === duration) window.clearInterval(interval);
};

// The onclick callback function should be a function
// that converts the user input to # of seconds and calls 'startCountDown' with that value:
document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    startCountDown(parseInt(document.getElementById("seconds").value));
});
```

if you remove the last part of registering the event handler, and say:

```
startCountDown(10);
```

you have a working example.